# At what moment does JAX-RS receive information about the key storage address from microprofile-config.properties?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jwt, jax-rs, keycloak

I have Java EE backend and I use Keycloak for auth.

I have Application extends class:

```
import org.eclipse.microprofile.auth.LoginConfig;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/")
@LoginConfig(authMethod = "MP-JWT", realmName = "private")
public class CargoServiceApplication extends Application {
}
```

And I have microprofile-config.properties too:

```
mp.jwt.verify.publickey.location=http://keycloak-test.local:8080/auth/realms/customer-service/protocol/openid-connect/certs
mp.jwt.verify.issuer=http://keycloak-test.local:8080/auth/realms/customer-service
```

1. Сan someone explain to me at what point in time JAX-RS gets the JWT config? And where does it store this configuration?
2. How can I reset stored config in runtime?

Thanks everyone!)